# How Can I get my excel script to continue until last cell with a numeric value?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I created a script. However, it starts at A2 and ends at A9.  When I included a number in A10 it didnt populate. How can I ge tthis script to be versatile?

For example, I may just have numeric values between A2:A4 or I may have A2:A11. Is it this possible? I have included my current script for review.

```js
        function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Set range C3:F9 on selectedSheet
           selectedSheet.getRange("C3:F9").setFormulasLocal
    ([["=SUM(C2*A3)","=SUM(D2*A3)","=SUM(E2*A3)","=SUM(F2*A3)"],  ["=SUM(C2*A4)","=SUM(D2*A4)","=SUM(E2*A4)","=SUM(F2*A4)"],["=SUM(C2*A5)","=SUM(D2*A5)","=SUM(E2*A5)","=SUM(F2*A5)"],["=SUM(C2*A6)","=SUM(D2*A6)","=SUM(E2*A6)","=SUM(F2*A6)"],["=SUM(C2*A7)","=SUM(D2*A7)","=SUM(E2*A7)","=SUM(F2*A7)"],["=SUM(C2*A8)","=SUM(D2*A8)","=SUM(E2*A8)","=SUM(F2*A8)"],["=SUM(C2*A9)","=SUM(D2*A9)","=SUM(E2*A9)","=SUM(F2*A9)"]]);
}
```

I haven't tried anything as of yet. I am still researching how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `lastRow` is row# of the non-blank cell on Col A
- Use `setFormulaLocal` to apply formulas on `C3:Fx` (x=lastRow)

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let lastRow = selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").getLastCell().getRangeEdge(ExcelScript.KeyboardDirection.up).getRowIndex() + 1;
    selectedSheet.getRange("C3:F" + lastRow).setFormulaLocal("=SUM(C$2*A3)");
}
```

[image]

---

Update:

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let useRange = selectedSheet.getUsedRange();
    let formulaRange = useRange.getOffsetRange(2,2).getResizedRange(-2,-2);
    // console.log(formulaRange.getAddress());
    formulaRange.setFormulaLocal("=SUM(C$2*$A3)");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok i tried it and it came out like above. I have added a sample below. I need for the numbers to come out like the below picture i added if possible.

Comment: Please edit your post to share the image or data.

Comment: im trying it wont let me me. :( obviously im doing something wrong.

Comment: example" a3(91) c2(0.2) c3=sum (a3*c2) = 18.2

Comment: a4(90) c2(0.2) c4=sum(a4*c2) = 18

Comment: thank you that looks better but there aren't numbers in column b. i skipped that column. so a1:f1 are labeled rep1 - rep4 . c2:f2 are different decimals like you have and a3:a9 are whole numbers just like you have it.  also is it possible to do the columns similar to how you have for a where the columns can be like a1:f 1or a1: f11? also i didnt really have to skip column b it just happened like that. so if its better to not skip b and just slide the numbers over (left) thats fine. please and thank you for your help

Comment: It doesn't matter if col B are numbers or not. The code doesn't touch col B. What's wrong with the code now? please edit your post to share sample data. `like a1:f 1or a1: f11` What's it?

Comment: the way you have it set up is similar to my setup. except for column b3:b10. I don't have any numbers for column B, its just blank. for example [a3(90)*c2(0.2)= c3(18)] [a4(90)*c2(0.2)=c4(18)] [a5(91)*c2(0.2)=c5(18.2)] [a3(90)*d2(0.2)=d3(18) a4(90)*d2(0.2)=d4(18)] [a3(90)*e2(0.3)=e3(27)] [a4(90)*e2(0.3)=e4(27)] [a5(91)*(e2)=e5(27.3)]

Comment: for example i might have numbers for a3:a7 or i might have numbers for a3:a20. the same for c-f i might have 1 rep(c1) or 5 reps(c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1) i need the script to be able to adjust to what is in column a-the  beginning number in column a to whatever the last number in column a , also i need the script to adjust to the beginning row (c)- whatever the last letter may be in the row.            
 example: c1(rep1) d1(rep2) e1(rep3). c2:e2 represents decimals (0.1, 0.2, 0.3) c3:c? d3:d? e3:e? represents the output of a3*c2, or a3*d2 or a3*e2)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! That work!!! :) You have made so happy! Totally appreciate it!!